# Grouping nearby shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have two shapes that are near each other, one of them is selected. I need to be able to group it together with the selected shape.

Thanks for your help!

Here's the code I came with but it doesn't seem to match the nearby shape.  In particular its not finding a 20ptx20pt rectangle offset about half its with to the left and half its height to the top:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
Dim oSl As slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oSh2 As Shape
    
Dim MainHeight As Long
Dim MainWidth As Long

MainHeight = 48.76
MainWidth = 88.45
    
    
Set oSl = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

        For Each oSh2 In oSl.Shapes
            If IsWithinRangey(oSh, oSh2, 0.4) Then
                oSh2.Select (False)
            End If
        Next
''        ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Group
    
End Sub

Function IsWithinRangey(oSh As Shape, oSh2 As Shape, _
    AreaTolerance As Single) As Boolean
' Is the shape within the coordinates supplied?

    Dim WidthMin As Single
    Dim WidthMax As Single
    Dim HeightMin As Single
    Dim HeightMax As Single

    With oSh
    
        HeightMin = oSh.Height * (1 - AreaTolerance)
        HeightMax = oSh.Height * (1 + AreaTolerance)
        WidthMin = oSh.Width * (1 - AreaTolerance)
        WidthMax = oSh.Width * (1 + AreaTolerance)
    
        Debug.Print "==========================="
        Debug.Print "Shp: " & .Width & " x " & .Height
        Debug.Print "Min: " & WidthMin & " x " & HeightMin
        Debug.Print "Max: " & WidthMax & " x " & HeightMax
    End With

       
   With oSh2
   
        If oSh.Id <> oSh2.Id Then
            ShapeLeft = oSh.Left - (19.85) / 1
            ShapeTop = oSh.Top - (19.85) / 1
            
            Debug.Print ShapeLeft
            Debug.Print ShapeTop
            
            
            If .Left >= ShapeLeft And .Left < ShapeLeft + WidthMax Then
                If .Top >= ShapeTop And .Top < ShapeTop + HeightMax Then
                    If .Width >= WidthMin And .Width <= WidthMax Then
                        If .Height > HeightMin And .Height < HeightMax Then
                            IsWithinRangey = True
                    End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Please post sample slides to a cloud service, then post a share link here. It would be good to include a slide that works as expected along with the one that doesn't.

Comment: Choose Debug | Compile in the IDE to pinpoint a few problems (undeclared variables).  Your problem might also be due to the fact that you've DIMmed MainHeight and MainWidth as Longs. PowerPoint won't throw an error when you assign a value like 48.76 to a Long variable; it'll just round it to the nearest whole number. DIM these as Singles instead. If you need to know what type of variable PPT uses internally, press F2 for the Object Browser and look up the property you want to work with. It'll tell you how to DIM it in the window below.

Comment: @JohnKorchok, here your are! [bold][link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1--gimFwzVAM7oyXwqppNC0W_gpnhBx7U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I dimmed them as Single as still no luck. It still grabs the textbox to the right which is supposedly out of bounds

Comment: @Miguel You uploaded pictures of your presentation, not a presentation file. I don't have the time to re-create your file from pictures, sorry.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Sorry about the misunderstanding.  Here are the slides ]bold]]link]https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1-6u0gpgrarmaGO0T02hH7xaPl5mjMbnA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117481557309517620436&rtpof=true&sd=true[link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code more efficient, I would restructure as follows:

```
Dim WidthMin As Single
Dim WidthMax As Single
Dim HeightMin As Single
Dim HeightMax As Single

Sub GroupCloseShapes()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oSh2 As Shape
    Dim MainHeight As Long
    Dim MainWidth As Long

    MainHeight = 48.76
    MainWidth = 88.45

    Set oSl = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    With oSh
        HeightMin = oSh.Height * (1 - AreaTolerance)
        HeightMax = oSh.Height * (1 + AreaTolerance)
        WidthMin = oSh.Width * (1 - AreaTolerance)
        WidthMax = oSh.Width * (1 + AreaTolerance)
    End With
    
    For Each oSh2 In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.ID <> oSh2.ID Then
            If IsWithinRangey(oSh, oSh2, 0.4) Then
                oSh2.Select (False)
            End If
        End If
    Next
'' ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Group
End Sub

Function IsWithinRangey(oSh As Shape, oSh2 As Shape, AreaTolerance As Single) As Boolean ' Is the shape within the coordinates supplied?
    With oSh2
        .Select
        ShapeLeft = oSh.Left - (19.85) / 1
        ShapeTop = oSh.Top - (19.85) / 1
        Debug.Print ShapeLeft
        Debug.Print ShapeTop
        If .Left >= ShapeLeft And .Left < ShapeLeft + WidthMax Then
            If .Top >= ShapeTop And .Top < ShapeTop + HeightMax Then
                If .Width >= WidthMin And .Width <= WidthMax Then
                    If .Height > HeightMin And .Height < HeightMax Then
                        IsWithinRangey = True
                End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

I've added a **.Select** method to make it clear which shape is currently being checked. Your problem is with the math calculations in the IsWithinRangey function. To debug them, click on the grey bar to the left of the code. This inserts a breakpoint:
[image: Breakpoint]

Run the macro. It will stop at the breakpoint. Press **F8** to step through each statement. Hover your mouse over the variable names to see their current values. Then adjust your calculations to find the shape you want and ignore the shape you don't want.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKorcok! Worked out the kinks and now works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JohnKorchok! Final code follows

```
Option Explicit

Dim WidthMax As Single
Dim HeightMax As Single
Dim ShapeLeft As Single
Dim ShapeTop As Single
Dim AreaTolerance As Single
Dim StepNumberWidth As Single
Dim StepNumberHeight As Single
Dim oNewShape As Shape


Sub GroupCloseShapes()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oSh2 As Shape
    Dim MainHeight As Long
    Dim MainWidth As Long

    MainHeight = 48.76
    MainWidth = 88.45
    StepNumberWidth = 19.85
    StepNumberHeight = 19.85
    
    Set oSl = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    With oSh
        HeightMax = oSh.Height * (1 + AreaTolerance)
        WidthMax = oSh.Width * (1 + AreaTolerance)
        ShapeLeft = oSh.Left - StepNumberWidth / 1
        ShapeTop = oSh.Top - StepNumberHeight / 1
        
    End With
    
    For Each oSh2 In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.Id <> oSh2.Id Then
            If IsWithinRangey(oSh, oSh2, 0.4) Then
                oSh2.Select (False)
            End If
        End If
    Next
'' ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Group
End Sub

Function IsWithinRangey(oSh As Shape, oSh2 As Shape, AreaTolerance As Single) As Boolean ' Is the shape within the coordinates supplied?
    With oSh2
        If .Left >= ShapeLeft And .Left <= ShapeLeft + WidthMax Then
            If .Top >= ShapeTop And .Top <= ShapeTop + HeightMax Then
                If .Width <= WidthMax Then
                    If .Height <= HeightMax Then
                        IsWithinRangey = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Function
```